# Android Studio: duplicate packages in "project structure" pane

Tags: android-studio

I have this annoying duplication of package view groups (`com.domain`) in "project structure" (`Alt+1`) pane:

[image]

Packages `com.domain.*` are being "split" between these two view groups. Why this happen and how can I fix it (i.e. see a single `com.domain` package view group with all sub-packages in it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This duplication was caused by auto-generated code: one of the libraries we use (GreenDAO) generated code into `entities` package under `build` folder (same package also exists under `src` folder)..

Android studio just showed the auto-generated classes under a separated package with the same name as the original package. This makes sense because we wouldn't want to accidentally edit auto-generated files while editing source code.