# Auto Package Duplication in Test Directory of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, junit, duplicates

I was preparing some tests for my module in android studio and everything was working fine, but yesterday when I opened my project again, I found an **auto-generated copy of my test package**. 
when I tried to delete it, my **original package got deleted with it**. 
today I tried to create a package again and the problem is still persisting, and **it is only occurring in the "tests" folder**

 
**structure at Android level:** Duplicate at Android level
[image]
**structure at Project level:** only one package at Project level
[image]

I found a similar question here but it defers a bit: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121266/android-studio-duplicate-packages-in-project-structure-pane) 
he found the problem was due to one of his dependencies which were auto-generating the code, but my project structure was fine for a week, the problem occurred just recently. and I've hard-coded the dependency versions so there's no way it might have happened due to an update.

Although Just in case, This are my dependencies:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the same issue and `gradle sync` solved it. Hope it could help you as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).